# AND/AndAlso with Or/OrElse confusion

Tags: vb.net

I need to ensure the first item has a entry. (This is an import of a CSV file). 
The intended action is if Item(471)).ToString is blank but there is a value >0 in either Item(475)).ToString) or Item(479)).ToString) alert that a date is required.

I have tried a few ways and cannot get this to work. If I take the OrElse statement out and use only one of the two it works. I am confused the proper syntax to get this to work.  Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

```
    If (MyList.Items.Item(471)).ToString = "" And CDec((MyList.Items.Item(475)).ToString) > 0D OrElse CDec((MyList.Items.Item(479)).ToString) > 0D Then
        MessageBox.Show("FUELING DATE #1 CANNOT BE BLANK", "Critical Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else
        tbDate1.Text = (MyList.Items.Item(471)).ToString
    End If
```

Comment: What's the confusion, `AndAlso / OrElse` 'short circuit'? `IF 1 = 0 And 1 = 1` will evaluate both conditions, even though it knows the first condition isn't true. In cases where a function is in your if-line, this can lead to unexpected results. `IF 1 = 0 AndAlso 1 = 1" checks 1 = 0`, evaluates to false, and ditches the if-branch. Likewise with `Or`, which evaluates all conditions, even if first succeeds. `OrElse` continues forward only if it still needs to find a match. You might do `If ToyInBox("truck") OrElse ToyInPocket("truck")`, `ToyInPocket()` is only checked if `ToyInBox()` is false

Comment: If you're confused, it's because you didn't listen well enough in maths class when taught about operator precedence.  In Boolean logic, `AND` takes precedence over `OR` so you must use parentheses if you want an `OR` operator evaluated before an `AND` operator.  It's exactly the same situation us using parentheses to for an addition to be evaluated before a multiplication in a basic arithmetic expression.

Comment: As for using choosing between `And`/`Or` and `AndAlso`/`OrElse`, that's irrelevant to this question. Either would work in this particular case but you should always work by the following rule: ALWAYS use `AndAlso`/`OrElse` unless you specifically don't want short-circuiting and, if you don't want short-circuiting then you probably ought to rethink your design to avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

```
If (MyList.Items.Item(471)).ToString = "" AndAlso (CDec((MyList.Items.Item(475)).ToString) > 0D OrElse CDec((MyList.Items.Item(479)).ToString) > 0D) Then
    MessageBox.Show("FUELING DATE #1 CANNOT BE BLANK", "Critical Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
Else
    tbDate1.Text = (MyList.Items.Item(471)).ToString
End If
```

In short

```
If condition1 AndAlso (condition2 OrElse condition3) Then
```

Comment: My overall error was that I had forgotten I needed Parenthesis around my OrElse statement. Thanks for the help.